# How to set the 'time part' of an existing date variable to now

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

In Javascript, I want to update only the time part (HH:MM:ss) of an existing Date type variable to "now" time part:

let's say d is an existing variable in the code...

```
var d = new Date('2015-10-12 20:00:00');
var now = new Date();
d.setHours(now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds());
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you facing any issue with this?

Comment: that seems short, concise and does the job, what else do you need?

Comment: it seems short but it uses 4 different function (initialize, 3*getters) to do 1 simple action. I'm not facing any problem, just wondering if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:
new Date(d.getTime() + (now - d)%(24*3600 * 1000))
This will create a new Date instance.